# Decorating a single flower box with $4$ spaces with $4$ differently colored flowers, so that there is no flower box with more than $1$ yellow flower.

Tags: combinatorics

### What we are actually talking about

- Available flowers: Pink, Red, Yellow and Blue ($4$ distinct kinds).
- Available spots in the flower box: $4$.
- Restriction: Max. $1$ yellow flower in the flower box.
- We do not care about the order of the flowers in the flower box.
- Repetitions are allowed.

$\rightarrow$ We are dealing with a **multiset**.

Therefore we have to use the Binomial coefficient ${n+k-1}\choose{k}$ to determine how many possible combinations of $4$ elements there are, where the order doesn't matter and repetitions are occuring.

We would like to choose $k$ elements out of $n+k-1$, where $k-1$ is the amount of separators needed, to separate $k$ elements from each other. $n$ is the amount of elements we have to initially choose from, before adding the separators.

This gives us ${{4+4-1}\choose{4}}={{7}\choose{4}}=35$ ways to arrange $4$ flowers in a multiset.

Furthermore we have the restriction, that the maximum amount of yellow flowers in the flower box is not allowed to exceed $1$. Considering that, we have to substract all the possible combinations $yyxx,yyyx,yyyy$ involving more than $1$ yellow flower, from $35$ ($x$ is a placeholder for the $3$ remaining colors). We have to keep $yxxx$, as those combinations are containing a single yellow flower, which is allowed.

This gives us the following subset cardinalities:

$\vert\{yyyy\}\vert=1$

$\vert\{yyyx\}\vert=3$

$\vert\{yyxx\}\vert=6$

$\Rightarrow 35 -(1+3+6)=25$

**Problem:** The solution in my textbook says $24$.

What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: It would help make your argument more complete to explain where the remaining numbers come from.  For the case $yyxx$, you have two available spaces for non-yellow flowers.  The number of options then is the number of solutions to $x_1+x_2+x_3 = 2$ which we know to be $\binom{2+3-1}{3-1} = \binom{4}{2}=6$.  I agree with your solution and logic.  That being said, I agree with your logic and your answer.  Solution keys can occasionally have mistakes.

Comment: Alternatively, count the number of solutions with exactly zero yellow, and exactly one yellow, being $\binom{4+3-1}{3-1}+\binom{3+3-1}{3-1} = \binom{6}{2}+\binom{5}{2}=25$ as well.

Comment: Okay, so this indicates that the solution in my university textbook is wrong... This task was in an exam about discrete math, so rip to all those who got it actually right. Wow, this gave me a fair amount of headaches. Thanks for the help!